# How to import DXF file with exact scale in blender

Tags: import, units, measurement

I have import the DXF file in blender. The walls have 6 inch thickness in the CAD file. And when i imported in Blender the scale looks wrong.

[DXF file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T4tttUvyjBqrvcvUsNNEOvjuMlgmt7Rx/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

**Note : I do not want to scale down the mesh and adjust in Blender**

Any perfect way to import the DXF file with exact measurements. Thanks

Comment: How did you import the DWG?

Comment: @mugnozzo sorry it was DXF i have mention DWG. File-> import-> DWG and click

Comment: It looks to me like the DXF Importer is broken. Somewhat broken in 2.79 and really broken in 2.83 (and up).

Comment: I guess I should elaborate: Scaling of the DXF does not affect the font size like it should, and in 2.8 and up it is not possible to import the DXF centered, checking that box throws a Python error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a far from perfect answer, and ignores "**I do not want to scale down the mesh and adjust in Blender.**" But it presents a method that should work reasonably well.

1. There is a bug in the Blender DXF importer (0.9.6) created by the changes between Blender 2.79 and 2.8x. There is a simple fix, though. Edit the file do.py found in the addons folder. For example:

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfimport\do.py

Change line 1400 from:

```
      bpy.context.screen.scene = scene
```

to

```
      bpy.context.window.scene = scene
```

2. Import the .dxf file making sure to check the "Center geometry to scene" button in the merge options.
3. With all the elements selected press <kbd>s</kbd> to enter scale mode and then type 0.0254 to scale the objects to the exact size. This number is the conversion factor from inches, your DXF file default, to meters, Blender's internal default.

[image: Results screenshot]
Note: I didn't use snapping to do the measurement so it's off a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since my Autocad file is in Inches (Check your AutoCAD units with the command `dwgunits` , by default should be option "1" in inches). If so, export the Autocad DWG to DXF  (I always use the Version 2000).

Then when in Blender, using the Import-export AutoCAD DXF addon (still in version 0.9.6) Select the *File > Import > Autocad DXF* and go to the side menu *Merge Options* on the right and scroll down till you find *DXF File Unit Scale* and type: `0.0254` (that's 1 inch in metric system) and the import.

You should have your drawing reference in scale. Just switch your units to imperial Inches in the scene properties menu on the right (the one with the cone and sphere icon).

Now measure one part of the drawing with the measure tool( <kbd>T</kbd> menu) and check.